# Split a column into two columns using tidyr separate

Tags: r, tidyr

I need to split a column into two columns.
My data is in csv file, and I imported that into R.
This is the code I am using
installed `tidyr` package

```
data$CarName <- separate(data$CarName, c("Car Name", "Car Model"), sep = " ")
```

error

> Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Any help?

Comment: `separate` works on a dataframe and not on a column.  It may be `separate(data, carName ,into = c("CarName", "CarModel"), sep= " ")`  It is better to show a small reproducible example

Comment: Put your data head in your question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data from the .csv file was separated with spaces, you might want to look into `str_split_fixed` from the `stringr` package. Based on the info you provided, the code would look something like this:

```
 carname <- "Carname CarModel"
 data <- data.frame(carname)
 data$name <- str_split_fixed(data$carname,n = 2,pattern = " ")[1]
 data$model <- str_split_fixed(data$carname,n = 2,pattern = " ")[2]
```

Resulting in:

```
 data
           carname    name    model
 1 Carname CarModel Carname CarModel
```

If your data was, e.g. comma-seperated, just replace the pattern in the `str_split_fixed`.